# Display realtime data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm sending data from my backend every 10 seconds and I wanted to display that data in reactjs. I've searched on the net to use socket.io to display real-time data. Is there a better way to use it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're dead set on updating your data every 10 seconds, it would make more sense to **make a request from the client to the server**, as HTTP requests can only be opened from client to server. By using HTTP requests, you won't need to use socket.io, but socket.io is an easy alternative if you need much faster requests.

Depending on how you are generating the data being sent from your backend, specifically if you are using a database, there is most likely a way to subscribe to changes in the database. This would **actually update the data in realtime**, without a 10 second delay.

If you want a more detailed answer, you'll have to provide more detail regarding your question: what data are you sending? where is it coming from or how are you generating it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an autodialer feature, in which an agent will get a call when I trigger the button from the frontend (using react js language), and then automatically all the leads in the agent assigned portal will get back-to-back calls from agent number. However, because this process is automatic, the agent won't know who the agent has called, so I want to establish a real-time connection so that I can show a popup on the frontend that contains information about the lead who was called.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't ask for help in an answer. If the other answers in this question don't give you what you need, please post a new question.